# Nuxt 3: reload/refresh the page

Tags: nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 2 we have `this.$nuxt.refresh()` which reloads the current page. Does Nuxt 3 have the same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use reloadNuxtApp in nuxt 3

read the docs :
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/reload-nuxt-app